# Getting null values in my array of struct in c, improper freeing

Tags: c, arrays, struct, null, free

I had my program printing out the words in a file and incrementing when they appeared more than once. I am now getting just "NULL" and the count as "17" instead. I can't find anything that I changed but am not sure if it is because I haven't figured out how to properly free up my arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BASE 5
#define MAX 50

typedef char *string;

struct wordCount 
{
string word; 
unsigned int count;
}; 

int main (void)
{
unsigned int i; 
unsigned int found; 
unsigned int arraysize; 
unsigned int newsize; 
char temp [40];  
struct wordCount* wordArray; 

FILE *infile; 
arraysize = 0; 
infile = fopen("input.txt","r");
wordArray = malloc(BASE * sizeof(struct wordCount)); 

/*store in word from infile to struct, increment counter each time it appears*/ 
while (fscanf(infile, "%s", temp) == 1) { 
    found = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++){
        if(strcmp(temp,wordArray[i].word) == 0){
            wordArray[i].count++;
            found++; 
        } 
     }
     if (found== 0){
        if (arraysize<BASE){     
            wordArray[arraysize].word = (char 
                          *)malloc((strlen(temp)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(wordArray[arraysize].word,temp); 
            wordArray[arraysize].count = 1; 
            arraysize++;  
         } else {
          wordArray = realloc(wordArray, arraysize * sizeof(struct wordCount)); 
          wordArray[arraysize].word = (char *)malloc((strlen(temp)+1) * 
                 sizeof(char));
          strcpy(wordArray[arraysize].word,temp); 
          wordArray[arraysize].count = 1; 
          arraysize++; 
        }
     }
}

fclose(infile);  
/*newsize = SearchAndDestroy(wordArray, arraysize); */

for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
    printf("%s ", wordArray[arraysize].word);
    printf("%d\n", wordArray[arraysize].count); 
    /*free(wordArray[i].word);*/
}
/* and when done:*/
free(wordArray); 

return 0; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't tracking things properly. You need to pay more attention to the fact that "How many words I have", "how many words I have room for", and "how many words I would like to have room for" are three distinct items that need to all be tracked separately. In particular, it doesn't look like your call to `realloc()` is correct.